# Using OnValidateIdentity to perform additional validation on cookie data

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, katana

On [Brock Allen's blog](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/), he states that

> the CookieAuthenticationOptions class has a Provider property ... and
>   it has properties which are delegates you can subscribe to. This
>   allows you to validate the cookie as it comes into the application
>   (OnValidateIdentity). In this callback you can reject or replace the
>   identity.

I'm new to OWIN and C#, so am struggling to adapt the many examples of `OnValidateIdentity` that I've found online to suit my needs. After the cookie has been accepted as valid on each 'private' web page, I'd like to check for the following things:

1. The cookie contains at least one claim
2. The CustomerId claim value is greater than zero

I can achieve these two checks in a normal method, but I can't figure out how to hook the login into `OnValidateIdentity`.   Here's what I have so far:

I've written some code, but can't figure out what needs to be returned from the method used.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    dynamic cookieExpirationPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

    CookieAuthenticationProvider prov = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
    prov.OnValidateIdentity = ctx =>
    {
        MyClaimsIdentityObject si = MyApp.Identity.Current();
        if (si == null || si.UserId == 0 || si.CustomerId == 0) {
            ctx.RejectIdentity();
            // what needs to happen here for a return value?
        }
    };


    CookieAuthenticationOptions coa = new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        CookieName = "MyApp",
        ExpireTimeSpan = cookieExpirationPeriod,
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/login.aspx"),
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        Provider = prov
    };

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal) {
        coa.CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never;
    } else {
        coa.CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always;
    }

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(coa);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is just:

```
return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
```

Comment: There's a full example here that achieves a similar thing to what I needed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780551/extending-cookieauthenticationprovider-onvalidateidentity